# DSolve doesn't find formal solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have another question regarding DSolve, I hope it's permitted to ask it.

I have to find a solution to the following problem with a differential equation:

```
DSolve[{x''[t] == (x'[t]^2 - 4 x[t]^4)/x[t], x[0] == 1, x[1] == 1.2}, x[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

but mathematica just echoes my code and doesn't compute.

Writing the following code

```
s = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == (x'[t]^2 - 4 x[t]^4)/x[t], x[0] == 1, 
x[1] == 1.2}, {x}, {t, -5, 8}];
Plot[Evaluate@Through[s[t]], {t, -5, 8}]
```

I get the plot of the solution, but what I really need is the formal solution of the problem with the differential equation and the border conditions.

How should it be done?

Comment: Do you know there is a symbolic solution?

Comment: I think yes, because it's a differential equation rising from the geodesic equations of a riemannian metric

Comment: the first one, sorry I'll edit it.

Comment: yes it seems so

Comment: When I run your `NDSolve` code, I obtain numerous error messages and a curve for which `x[0] == 0.5`.

Comment: you're right, my bad, the solution of NSolve verifies x[0]=0.5 instead of 1. what do you think it means?

Comment: Perhaps, there is no solution satisfying those boundary conditions.  This is possible for nonlinear equations.

Answer (score 4):

**With little help MMA can find general and particular solution**

```
ode = x''[t] - (x'[t]^2 - 4*x[t]^4)/x[t]
```

A new variable `x[t]=1/v[t]`:

```
xx[t_] := v[t]^(-1);
ode2 = FullSimplify[(ode /. x -> xx)*v[t]^3] // Expand
sol = DSolve[ode2 == 0, v[t], t]
```

> $\left\{\left\{v(t)\to \frac{1}{2} e^{-e^{c_1} t-2 c_1-e^{c_1} c_2}
>    \left(e^{2 e^{c_1} \left(c_2+t\right)}+4 e^{2
>    c_1}\right)\right\},\left\{v(t)\to \frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-e^{c_1}
>    t-2 c_1-e^{c_1} c_2}+4 e^{e^{c_1} t+e^{c_1}
>    c_2}\right)\right\}\right\}$

Back  substituting:

```
sol2 = x[t] -> 1/v[t] /. sol
```

> $\left\{x(t)\to \frac{2 e^{e^{c_1} t+2 c_1+e^{c_1} c_2}}{e^{2 e^{c_1}
>    \left(c_2+t\right)}+4 e^{2 c_1}},x(t)\to \frac{2}{e^{-e^{c_1} t-2
>    c_1-e^{c_1} c_2}+4 e^{e^{c_1} t+e^{c_1} c_2}}\right\}$

Check the results, can be verified:
 First  and second solution :

```
 (ode /. sol2[[1]] /. D[sol2[[1]], t] /. D[sol2[[1]], t, t]) == 
 0 // FullSimplify
 (*True*)
 (ode /. sol2[[2]] /. D[sol2[[2]], t] /. D[sol2[[2]], t, t]) == 
 0 // FullSimplify
 (*True*)
```

Now You must find the constants `c1` and `c2`,numerically only.
Let's take the first solution of the equation `sol2` and find constans:

```
 sol3 = FindRoot[{(x[t] /. sol2[[1]] /. t -> 0 /. C[1] -> c1 /. 
  C[2] -> c2) == 
 1, (x[t] /. sol2[[1]] /. t -> 1 /. C[1] -> c1 /. C[2] -> c2) == 
 6/5}, {{c1, 0.1 - I}, {c2, 0.5 - I}}]

  (*{c1 -> 0.979599 - 0.797296 I, c2 -> 0.138683 + 0.212765 I} *)



 sol4 = sol2[[1]] /. C[1] -> c1 /. C[2] -> c2 /. sol3
```

> $x(t)\to \frac{2 e^{(1.86076\, -1.90557 i) t+(2.62269\, -1.46296 i)}}{e^{(3.72152\, -3.81115
>    i) (t+(0.138683\, +0.212765 i))}+(-0.675155-28.3665 i)}$

**Checks boundary conditions:**

```
 x[t] /. sol4 /. t -> 0
 (* 1. - 5.55112*10^-17 I *)
 x[t] /. sol4 /. t -> 1
 (* 1.2 - 5.55112*10^-17 I*)
```

.

```
 s = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == (x'[t]^2 - 4 x[t]^4)/x[t], x[0] == 1, 
 x[1] == 1.2}, {x}, {t, -5, 8}];
```

In this case  `NDSolveValue` spit out `Power::infy` and fails.

```
 Plot[{Re@Evaluate[x[t] /. sol4], Evaluate@Through[s[t]]}, {t, -5, 8}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Solution with FindRoot", "NDSolve"}]
```

[image]

Comment: The plot does not have `x[0] == 1`.

Comment: @  bbgodfrey .Yep you are right.

Comment: It's  very probably the system  {(x[t] /. sol2[[1]] /. t -> 0 /. C[1] -> c1 /. 
  C[2] -> c2) ==  1, (x[t] /. sol2[[1]] /. t -> 1 /. C[1] -> c1 /. C[2] -> c2) == 
 6/5} has complex solutions only.

Comment: @user64494  .Thanks for info.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that there is no solution to the ODE system given in the question due to inconsistent boundary conditions.  Certainly, [Mariusz Iwaniuk](http://Mariusz%20Iwaniuk), the OP, and I have tried without success to obtain a solution, both symbolically and numerically.  On the other hand, with consistent boundary conditions both symbolic and numerical solutions can be obtained readily.  For instance, with `x[1] == 2/5`, the numerical solution is

```
s = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == (x'[t]^2 - 4 x[t]^4)/x[t], x[0] == 1, x[1] == 2/5}, 
    x, {t, 1}]; 
Plot[s[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

[image]

and the corresponding symbolic solution,

```
ss = (x[t] /. First@DSolve[{x''[t] == (x'[t]^2 - 4 x[t]^4)/x[t]}, x[t], t, 
    Assumptions -> x > 0] // Simplify) /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}
(* (2 c1 E^(Sqrt[c1] (c2 + t)))/(4 c1 + E^(2 Sqrt[c1] (c2 + t))) *)
```

Boundary conditions are imposed by

```
fr = {ss /. t -> 0, ss /. t -> 1};
con = FindRoot[Thread[fr == {1, 2/5}], {{c1, 8}, {c2, 1}}]
(* {c1 -> 6.30464, c2 -> 0.36378} *)
```

The plot of `ss/.con` is identical to that above.

**Addendum: Upper bound on x[1](http://Mariusz%20Iwaniuk)**

The upper bound on `x[1]` can be found as follows.

```
NMaximize[{fr[[2]], fr[[1]] == 1, 0 <= c1}, {c1, c2}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* {0.401412731593713172432788279860, 
   {c1 -> 6.80483818872865062735255300019, c2 -> 0.341320047083856817600759895202}} *)
```

Thus, the upper bound on `x[1]` is about 0.4014127, and both the `ss` and `con` computations fail (or give complex-number solutions, which is equally unsatisfactory) for `x[1] == 0.4014128`.

Comment: Exactly saying, you demonstrate there is  no real-valued solution of the ODE under consideration.

Comment: @user64494  The upper bound on `x[1]` is about 0.4014127, as shown in the addendum to my answer.